# Mixed mode assembly is built against version v.2.0.50727 error on 64 bit computer but not 32 bit laptop

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010

Afternoon

I've recently been working on a solution which is built targetting .net 4.0.

We are referencing a .dll which has its Runtime version set to 2.0.50727 in the property window.

I have the following tags in the app.config file as per the other questions on this subject :

```
<startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client" />
```

Now, when I run this software on the 32 bit laptop, it runs fine. When I run it on the 64 bit desktop I get the following error message

> Mixed mode assembly is built against version 2.0.50727 of the runtime and cannot be loaded in the 4.0 runtime without additional config information.

Both the laptop and the desktop are running .net version 4.

I was wondering if there is a system file for visual sudio or in the SDK folder that I need to modify or if anyone has any other suggestions.

Thanks

Comment: It is complaining that it cannot see the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true" attribute.  It is of course unclear why, you can see which .config file it uses by running Fuslogvw.exe and logging all binds.  Just in case: don't forget that your need yourapp.vshost.exe.config file if you have the Visual Studio Hosting process option enabled.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ",Profile=Client" portion of the "sku" attribute?

Comment: Although it is a bit dated (March 2010), there is quite a bit of detailed information about the behavior of the useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy attribute at http://web.archive.org/web/20130128072944/http://www.marklio.com/marklio/PermaLink,guid,ecc34c3c-be44-4422-86b7-900900e451f9.aspx. This is often tied to the behavior of apps that interact at some level with unmanaged assemblies.

Comment: @David I have not - I didn't think changing the config file would fix it though given that the application works when run on the laptop. I'll give it a try though

Comment: @GioSfoza Admittedly a long shot but sometimes I've had annoying little one-off issues arise from that "client" profile, maybe a red herring :)

Comment: Is the app's Platform target x86, x64, or AnyCPU?  I would expect a BadImageFormatException on x64 if the Platform target was wrong.  Is the mixed mode assembly x86 or x64?

Comment: @mcdon It's currently set to AnyCPU

Comment: @GioSfoza Try rebuilding as x86 and running the new build on your 64 bit machine.  Mixed mode assemblies contain both managed and native code.  Since the app works on a 32 bit machine I'd assume your mixed mode assembly contains x86 native code.  An app built as AnyCPU runs as x64 on 64 bit machine, and x86 on a 32 bit machine.